# Import excel worksheet into vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel-import

I have got an excel worksheet which actually calculates the loan... If we input the amount and no. of years,it gives us a list of all the EMI's to be made in the coming years.

My boss wants to integrate that excel worksheet into vb.net form....How can I do so? Please help me....

Comment: Use interop. Do a quick search on google - interop read excel vb.net - and you will be given exactly what you need

Answer (score 3):

In your form add a `DataGrid "GridControl1"`    and a `button "BtnImport_Click` :

In your button `BtnImport_Click` add this code

```
  Private Sub BtnImport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnImport.Click
     Dim dialog As New OpenFileDialog()
                dialog.Filter = "Excel files |*.xls;*.xlsx"
                dialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
                dialog.Title = "Veuillez sélectionner le fichier à importer"
                'Encrypt the selected file. I'll do this later. :)
                If dialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then   
                    Dim dt As DataTable
                    dt = ImportExceltoDatatable(dialog.FileName)
                    GridControl1.DataSource = dt
                    GridControl1.Visible = True
                    MsgBox(" done ! ", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                End If
    End Sub
```

And add this `function` in your `form` :

```
  Public Shared Function ImportExceltoDatatable(filepath As String) As DataTable
                ' string sqlquery= "Select * From [SheetName$] Where YourCondition";
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                Try
                    Dim ds As New DataSet()
                    Dim constring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & filepath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"""
                    Dim con As New OleDbConnection(constring & "")

                    con.Open()

                    Dim myTableName = con.GetSchema("Tables").Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME")
                    Dim sqlquery As String = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", myTableName) ' "Select * From " & myTableName  
                    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlquery, con)
                    da.Fill(ds)  
                    dt = ds.Tables(0)
                    Return dt
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
                    Return dt
                End Try
            End Function
```

Hop that help you

Comment: Hello mate, thanks a lot for the help.... I have imported the excel file successfully in datagrid view.... But I am not able to do any operation on the excel sheet.....  Since in the excel sheet can do the loan calculation but while it gets imported in the datagridview, I am not able to do so... Please help me to sort out this problem

Comment: I have imported the excel file successfully in datagrid view.... But I am not able to do any operation on the excel sheet..... Since in the excel sheet can do the loan calculation but while it gets imported in the datagridview, I am not able to do so... Please help me to sort out this problem –

Comment: You want modify in gridview or in your Excel sheet ?

Comment: I want to modify inside the datagrid view

Comment: I know it's an older post, but you were very kind to post the code above.  I was able to use the Function without change.  Thanks!